# Building a list based on object state

Tags: php, oop

When building a list representing the state of some objects, should I ask each
object for its state and modify the list myself, or should I give the object
the list and tell it to add itself?

I'm building a list of templates for output on the page. The form element
requires this list be distilled down to a key/value pair. A coworker mentioned
that I should pay more attention to "Tell, Don't Ask" and I'm trying to
understand that principle with respect to this problem.

I've taken an approach where I create an instance of TemplateList
and then ask each template to add itself to the list. This allows the template
to determine which arguments it will pass to `TemplateList::addTemplate()`.

```
class TemplateList {
    public $templates = array();

    public function addTemplate($id, $label) {
        $this->templates[$id] = $label;
    }

    public function getTemplates() {
        return $templates;
    }
}

interface TemplateInterface {
    public function addToTemplateList(&$templatelist);
}

class DiskTemplate implements TemplateInterface {
    public function addToTemplateList(&$template_list) {
        $template_list->addTemplate($this->name, $this->name);
    }
}

class DatabaseTemplate implements TemplateInterface {
    public function addToTemplateList(&$template_list) {
        $template_list->addTemplate($this->id, $this->name);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
$template_list = new TemplateList;

// fetch $disk_templates and $db_templates

foreach ($disk_templates as $template) {
    $template->addToTemplateList($template_list);
}

foreach ($db_templates as $template) {
    $template->addToTemplateList($template_list);
}
```

An alternative approach would ask the template for its state and add the result to the template list:

```
$template_list = new TemplateList;

// fetch $template

$template_list->addTemplate($template->propertiesForTemplateList());
```

Is there an advantage to either approach? Is there something else entirely I haven't taken into consideration?

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is a little mistake in the principle: its "[Tell, don't ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask)" :). You can find a really nice article about this and other principles [here](http://alanknightsblog.blogspot.com.ar/2011/10/principles-of-oo-design-or-everything-i.html). The basic idea is that, instead of asking questions to your objects and then deciding what to do, you should just tell your objects what to do. Each object (e.g. based on its internal state) should know how to handle a task (message send). 
This is important in order to keep the responsibilities well assigned. If you ask something to an object, but decide what to do in another, you are spreading the intrinsic logic of one object into many. This yields code that is hard to test and maintain, since you don't have cohesive objects and a single place to modify/test the functionality. 
The second problem that arises here is encapsulation; in most cases the state of an object is private and people make it public so that the object can be queried for its state to later perform an action. As a general rule of thumb I consider that a smell, since you are (again) not only spreading an objects responsibility to the rest of the system but also violating the object's encapsulation. Note that I'm not saying here that getters are bad per-se, just that if you need to make your state public so that other object can take a decision for you, you may be going in the wrong track.

Now, going to your code, I think that the first approach is perfectly valid, since it is the object the one that knows how to add itself to the list and what properties should be used for that. You are keeping responsibilities well assigned and the internal state encapsulated if necessary.

HTH

Comment: Hah, whoops. I have the "Tell, Don't Ask" article up in a tab, just transposed the words. Fixed. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: You are welcome. If you can read Knight's article; not only it has the best pieces of advice I ever read about OO design, but it is also really easy to read.